# Multi-platform CI-tool?

Tags: continuous-integration, multiplatform

After looking around, I could not find a single CI tool that would make builds for multiple OS's.
Is there an overview of which tools support which? Is there a tool that supports multiple in the first place? (Like Travis supports OSX/Linux)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) is an open-source, multi-platform CI system. It runs on top of Java, so you can run build agents (and the master server) where-ever Java is available.

I use it successfully for over a year to build projects on Linux and Windows platforms (including complex build flows that require build/test steps on both platforms for a single project).

Jenkins also has hundreds of [plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/), many of them are actively developed by the community.